# How can I change chat sound notifications?

Tags: support, chat

The current notification sound is a little bit annoying. I thought the sound is the browser default sound but it is not. I heard a different sound the same browser in different chat rooms.

How can i change notification sound?

Comment: This is a meta question

Comment: @Alvar: It's not a meta question. A meta question is about the site itself, this question is about Ubuntu itself: changing the notify-osd sound, which does not have to be related to AU.

Comment: please explain yourself more Achu so we understand. IS it specific to AU or is it general for the browser?

Comment: @Alvar meta? how is this meta?...

@Achu you need to change the Sound theme on Sound preferences.

Comment: join the chat... I think it's a meta.....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've created an Userscript for it which is available at [SE Chat custom notification sound](https://stackapps.com/q/2479/6969).

After installation, you need to reload the page. The button will be available next to the "set audio notification level" button:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Good job! it is Awesome!....

Comment: http://victorychat.org/message_for_me ← this does't work (it's audio/x-wav). Any chance you can make this work?

Comment: You need to convert it to a MP3 file, it's stated explicitly in the description. I might make an upload feature that does that automatically, but I've yet some work to do like a backup plan that should have been completed two months ago :O

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

The SE Chat creates an [audio element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-audio-element) on the site to play the sound (or a Flash applet, if your browser doesn't support it). So the sound is hard coded into the system.

The only thing you can do is disable the sound altogether. Luckily, this is pretty granular:

[image]

Comment: You can't **yet**...