# Sweet ping sounds for AU rooms

Tags: feature-request, chat

I always feel the AU chat rooms ping sounds are not very good. *(They are intimidating, sometimes actually)*. I've recently joined [Stack Overflow Java](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java) and found that they are enjoying a very gorgeous ping sound.

I am impressed with the sound so much that, I request to our moderator to replace the ping sound of AU rooms to that of SO java room or  more sweeter one.

Comment: Related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1581/how-can-i-change-chat-sound-notifications

Comment: so "for" is for nicer sounds?

Comment: +1  It's ANNOYING!!!!

Answer (score 8):

### For

1. The sounds on Java room is a gentle one (to be nice to our room)
2. The theme on Ask Ubuntu is nice and the sounds should fit with that.
3. No one is liking it. (AU chat sound)
4. Looks like a harsh voice, when someone pings you
5. Sometimes that sound breaks my concentration ( here, it is Anwar)

**The sound suggestions:**

Our preference is as follows, (top indicate higher preference)

1. [Java Room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java)'s ping sound
2. [This old sound](http://or.cdn.sstatic.net/chat/sf.mp3) of Server Fault
3. [This sound](http://or.cdn.sstatic.net/chat/bonfire.mp3), which is also a Stack Exchange network sound. *(not sure which site)*

Comment: To answer your "not sure which site", it was a private instance of chat used for our company-internal rooms. This site doesn't exist anymore (the company-internal rooms are now on chat.meta)

Answer (score 2):

### Choose a custom sound

https://stackapps.com/questions/2479/se-chat-custom-notification-sound

The above script allows you to choose a custom sound for your Stack Echange rooms.

Comment: it's not working. I've tested that on FF 12

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [myself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139222/115866):

> Regarding the discussion about the sound choice, I'll say what I've said time and time again: Anything that is not *constructive* is in vain. Opinions on particular sounds are more subjective than on Jarrod's toe socks, so to change a notification sound, you have to a) offer an alternative, not just "the current one is bad, give us another one", and b) there has to be reasonable agreement that the new choice isn't worse than the old one. In such a case, we're happy to change notification sounds. The sounds for the no-longer-existing sites are still there, so you even have some suggestions to start with ([1](http://or.cdn.sstatic.net/chat/sf.mp3), [2](http://or.cdn.sstatic.net/chat/su.mp3), [3](http://or.cdn.sstatic.net/chat/bonfire.mp3), [4](http://or.cdn.sstatic.net/chat/ubuntu.mp3)).

Also note that (currently) the sound is identical per chat site, so all rooms on chat.stackoverflow.com have the same sound, and all rooms on chat.stackexchange.com (which includes the AU rooms) have the same sound.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've updated the answer with sound preference. i am sure, we will be able to modify/verify the preference list in a final state. Thanks

Comment: Please remember that the sound is used for *all* chat rooms on http://chat.stackexchange.com, so this should be brought to the whole network community. In other words, I'm asking you to at some point bring this to [metase] (which also serves as the network-wide meta site); this isn't an Ask Ubuntu-only thing.

Comment: how about choose your own sound, you could customize it with a small sound format file (stored on the users computer) or choose from the 3 or 4 defaults, and everyone would be happy!

Answer (score -2):

### Against

- The current sound is nice
- Users would be confused with another chat room's sound (aka using SO Java and AU at the same time)

Comment: Currently SO, SU, SF and AU have same sounds